# Multiple instances of jQuery countdown are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, countdown

i'm using a jQuery countdown plugin (can be downloaded here: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

I've implemented it and it works when there is a single instance (countdown) on a page, but when there are more than 1 instances, it doesn't work.

The code i'm using:

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    // Set some date in the past. In this case, it's always been since Jan 1
    var offerEndDateTS =  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', true); ?>;
    var offerEndDate = new Date(offerEndDateTS * 1000);
    austDay = new Date(offerEndDateTS * 1000);
    jQuery('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    jQuery('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());

});
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to make all counters on same page to work? Thanks for your time

Comment: I suggest you contact the author. [so] is not technical support for some script you downloaded from the web.

Comment: I did try to contact the author but no response yet. Besides that, i'm trying to implement the countdown in wordpress, and i dont think the author would want to help me on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine::

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div> //first
<div id="defaultCountdownSecond"></div> //second

<div id='featured_offer_countdown_template'>

     {d<}<div class='item days'>
        <span class='value'>{dn}</span>
       <span class='label'>{dl}</span>
     </div>{d>}          
    <div class='item hours'>
       <span class='value'>{hn}</span>
       <span class='label'>{hl}</span>
    </div>
    <div class='item minutes'>
       <span class='value'>{mn}</span>
        <span class='label'>{ml}</span>
    </div>
    <div class='item seconds'>
       <span class='value'>{sn}</span>
       <span class='label'>{sl}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
var austDay = new Date();
austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 5, 9);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
    until: austDay,
    format: 'dHMS'    
});
$('#defaultCountdownSecond').countdown({
    until: austDay,
    format: 'dHMS'    
});
$('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5852/)

Comment: thank you Sudhir for the quick reply. I forgot to mention that the counters are included within a wordpress loop. Now i've just changed $('#defaultCountdown') to $('#defaultCountdown<?php the_ID') and it generates different div id for each post. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Sudhir Out of interest, what is the `featured_offer_countdown_template` for?

Comment: @jammykam thats just a template id.. :)

Comment: @Sudhir Yes, I understand that, but what is that entire `div` used for in this example? It is not referenced in any of the JS. (I am not the OP btw)

Comment: @jammykam thats the default template id used to parse the values of {hn}, {dn}, etc.. you can check layout option of countdown for more details

Comment: @Sudhir Sure, but it is not passed in an a layout option in your code: http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#layout

Comment: @jammykam it also says "Leave as blank to use the built-in layouts." , so in our case the default layout is being used, the id is just any name given, but the variables will be parsed using built-in layouts in our case

Comment: @Sudhir Yes, that's what we have. It just confused me that you had the template but it wasn't referenced anywhere. Looks like it could be removed without any effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try reading the [reference documentation](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) or looking at the demos??

Seems to work fine for me:

HTML

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<div id="defaultCountdown2"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(2014, 1, 1)});
$('#defaultCountdown2').countdown({until: new Date(2015, 7, 1)});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/MQ9T4/)